# How to set the currently logged-in user information using spring security using a resource server?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to set or access the currently logged-in user information such as username.  My token is generated using client credential flow using Spring Authorization server.  So I am using the resource server specified in my test case like below:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
```

When I run my test case in Spring WebFlux I am not able to access the logged-in user using a code like below in my handler:

```java
LOG.info("user logged in is {}", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
```

I want to do something like following which I used to do for a custom authentication provider.:

```java
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwt.getSubject(), null, list);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
```

But now I am using the resource server to validate the token I am not sure how I can set the currently logged-in user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the username using the `ServerRequest` object such as follows from a Spring Security example:

```
serverRequest.principal()
            .map(Principal::getName)
            .flatMap(username ->
                ServerResponse.ok()..
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [an article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) for unit and integration testing with mocked OAuth2 `Authentication`.

In resource servers with JWT decoders, the default `Authentication` implementation is `JwtAuthenticationToken`. So, unless you explicitly changed that with a JwtAuthenticationConverter, you should populate the security context with a `JwtAuthenticationToken` (and not a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`).

When running a test with `WebTestClient` (or `WebMvc` in servlet apps), the security context is not built from the access token: it would require a real authorization server to serve an JWT public key or respond to introspection requests. The test security context is populated either by:

- the test itself with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(jwtAuthenticationToken)`
- a `WebTestClient` mutator (or `WebMvc` request post-processor): `webTestClient.mutateWith(SecurityMockServerConfigurers.mockJwt()...)`
- a test annotation from [a lib I maintain](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons):

```java
@Test
@WithMockJwt()
void whenUserIsAuthenticated_whenSomeQuery_thenSomeExpectation() {
}
```